# Urban Airship in app paurchase libSystem.B.dylib not found

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am trying to implement the api of Urban Airship. I tried executing their sample code for that but it gives me one error that is "file not found:/user/lib/libSystem.B.dylib".

Comment: I had the same problems.  I gave up with Urban Airship because of all the problems

Answer (score 0):

Oh Boy...

Try /**usr**/lib/libSystem.B.dylib instead...

Because you really are not going to find it in /user/lib/libSystem.B.dylib...

Good luck!